# Handling back button with Android Navigation with two navigation graphs

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-bottom-nav-view

I have created a small sample app to test out the android navigation library. The general idea is that I want two tabs with their own navigation graph.

My main activity layout contains a `BottomNavigationView` with two `NavHost`s.

The `ButtonNavigationView` click listener takes care of showing one `NavHost` or the other and also calling  `NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController` with the selected controller to update the toolbar accordingly. Up navigation is working fine.

The problem I am facing right now is the back button.

There is a property `app:defaultNavHost="true"` which ensures that your `NavHostFragment` intercepts the system back button, but I want that to be on/off depending on the active graph. I couldn't find a way to change it :(

I know I can override `onBackPressed()` but I am trying to find a way for the library to do that work for me letting it know which graph is active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [NavHostFragment source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/navigation/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/fragment/NavHostFragment.java#193), all that `app:defaultNavHost="true"` does is call through to [setPrimaryNavigationFragment()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction#setprimarynavigationfragment), which is how FragmentManager knows which child Fragment to send back button events to.

Therefore, when switching to a new Fragment, you can add `setPrimaryNavigationFragment()` to your FragmentTransaction to get the same behavior.

Comment: That worked! I ended up doing:

val tx = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
tx.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(selectedNavigation))
tx.commit()